# Differences/similarities of "Bitcoin script" and "Ethereum smart contract"?

Tags: script, ethereum, terminology

Can we compare `Bitcoin script` and `Ethereum smart contract` ?

And if yes,

What are **differences/similarities** of Bitcoin script and Ethereum smart contract in sense of functionality, architecture and how to interact with blockchain?

Does Bitcoin script run **on-chain** (similar to Ethereum smart contracts) or they run **off-chain**?

Answer (score 1):

As they say, Ethereum is Turing complete, Bitcoin script is intentionally not Turing complete.

Ethereum has a [virtual machine](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/introduction/what-is-ethereum.html#ethereum-virtual-machine) with a set of opcodes. Bitcoin script is defined by different opcodes, defined in [`src/script/script.h`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/script.h#L48). There are good descriptions of the opcodes at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script.

**Differences include:**

- Ethereum charges for each operation: https://github.com/djrtwo/evm-opcode-gas-costs to account for differences in computation difficulty.
- Bitcoin scripts are limited to a certain complexity (e.g. num of sigops) to prevent DoS attacks.

**Similarities include:**

- Contracts live on the blockchain. In an Ethereum-specific binary format (EVM bytecode), and in Bitcoin as Bitcoin Script.

> Does Bitcoin script run on-chain (similar to Ethereum smart contracts)
>   or they run off-chain?

Yes. Script can be stored in 3 places in a transaction: `witness`, `scriptSig` and `scriptPubkey`. These transactions are stored in blocks on the blockchain, and are run by nodes validating them.